# Variables declared in test setup must be nilable?

Tags: sorbet

I'm writing a test where I have a variable that I need to declare in the `setup do`.

```rb
typed: strict
frozen_string_literal: true

class BunnyTest
  extend(T::Sig)

  setup do
    @bunny = T.let(Bunny.new, Bunny)
  end

  test "#hop works correctly" do
    assert(@bunny.hop)
  end
end
```

When I run the type check, I get a message saying:

```
The instance variable @bunny must be declared inside initialize or declared nilable
```

Is there a way to treat ivar declarations in `setup do` just like ivar declarations in `#initialize`?

Comment: Can you just create an initializer, declare the variable there, and then call super to continue?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of alternatives for this

### A rewriter

If you use `Minitest`, there's a [rewriter in Sorbet](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/blob/de8eeedb4c0ba4392f2150e1ec9f734fecfe7dd2/rewriter/Minitest.cc) that will make this work for you.

You could write one for your testing framework of choice

### `__initialize` + method

This gets verbose, specially if you have more than one value you want to do this for

```rb
class BunnyTest
  extend(T::Sig)

  def __initialize__
    @bunny = T.let(nil, Bunny)
  end

  setup do
    @bunny = Bunny.new
  end

  def bunny
    T.must(@bunny)
  end

  test "#hop works correctly" do
    assert(bunny.hop)
  end
end
```

### Avoid `setup`

This is not responding your question, but an alternative that makes it unnecessary. I know there are cases where `setup` is helpful, but as a rule of thumb, I avoid it, and use explicit initialization in my test case. This makes it way easier to follow what's going on by just looking at the case, and avoids side effects/changes needed for other cases affecting the others:

```rb
class BunnyTest
  extend(T::Sig)

  sig {returns(Bunny)}
  def bunny
    Bunny.new
  end

  test "#hop works correctly" do
    assert(bunny.hop)
  end

  test "can #hop twice" do
    my_bunny = bunny
    assert(bunny.hop)
    assert(bunny.hop, "Should be able to hop a second time")
  end
end
```